# Android Studio Emulator not starting showing AVD was killed

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

[image]

I am unable to use emulator showing error the emulator process for AVD 'Device Name' was killed. tried every thing still not able to resolve this issue

also I am getting these error message

> handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed emulator: Android emulator version 30.7.5.0 (build_id 7491168) (CL:N/A)

Comment: I answered the same question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68480110/8150077 hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

you don't have enough space in your disk so if you can free up space in Windows you can launch the **Run** app by pressing **Windows key** with **R** or by searching for it.

After that type ***temp*** and click on **OK** button then a window will popup and delete everything in this folder by selecting them all and press **Shift** and **Delete** keys on the keyboard

now repeat the same steps but type ***%temp%*** instead of *temp*.

by doing this step you will free up space from 10GB to 20GB and maybe 30GB.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the problem was there is no enough space in my disk drive.

in the android studio Event layer section, you can see what happened

eg:Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Not enough space to create userdata partition. Available: 3310.363281 MB at /home/user/.android/avd/my_Nexus_5X_API_27.avd, need 7372.800000 MB."

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solutions:

1. Wipe your emulator data from AVD manager and cold boot[image]
2. Check the HAXM installer if you are using Intel(Hyper-v for AMD)

   Tools->SDK Manager->SDK Tools
   [image]

3.Check if you have enough space for an emulator on your hard drive.

4.Go to Settings->Emulator-> choose Launch in Window

5.Delete and create another device.

Comment: i tired this solution already but it didn't work. i have everything enable.

Comment: @RohitSainik Why did you accept the answer even though it was not working for you? Or was it working for you in the end?

Answer (score 0):

I [had a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70869849/398844) and was able to solve it by disabling Vulkan support for AVDs.

Basically you just have to add the following line to the file ***C:\Users\YourName\.android\advancedFeatures.ini*** on Windows or ***~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini*** on Linux and Mac:

```
Vulkan = off
```

Some more info can be found in [my original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70869850/398844).