# Android Device Manager has been killed

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator, emulation, android-virtual-device

Anytime I run my emulator for my AVD it says the emulator process for AVD pixel 2 has been killed.

I have tried several means online but I have been unable to get it fixed. I just installed android studio on my laptop and I have tried installing and reinstalling it again but isn't still working.

Comment: update your android emulator from Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android Sdk > Sdk Tools

Comment: Thank you for your response, But that exactly is the issue as I just download android studio and the packages that come with and so there is no update. BUt it still keeps giving the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Emulator version **30.7.5** has bugs which causes this. Try to downgrade to **30.7.4** by

1. download 30.7.4 from https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows_x64-7453540.zip
2. Locate emulator folder in SDK. And rename it to something like `emulator-to-delete`. For my case my SDK path is `C:\Users\Nux\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`
3. Extract the contents of zip folder you downloaded to folder named emulator.
4. Then copy `package` file from old emulator folder and paste it in emulator folder. Without this step Android Studio won't recognize emulator.
5. Now you can safely delete the other emulator folder.
6. Restart Android Studio and you are done.

Comment: Thank you Nux,
This worked although my system, was slow to open it