# Android emulator (AVD) crashes on Wayland + NVIDIA (GBM)

Tags: android-studio, nvidia, android-virtual-device, wayland

**Update:** The problem does not occur with the NVIDIA driver version 510 anymore.

I am running **Android Studio 2020.3.1 on Wayland** and I'm using the proprietary **NVIDIA driver version 495**, which allows me to use the the regular GBM implementation of Wayland instead of [the especially tailored EGL version](https://github.com/NVIDIA/egl-wayland).

My problem is, that every time I try to start an Android emulator (AVD) via the AVD Manager, I get the following message after a few seconds:

> The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_30 has terminated.

Starting the AVD from the command-line shows that a segmentation fault occurred:

```
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.1.4.0 (build_id 7920983) (CL:N/A)
WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.
INFO    | Info: Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway. ((null):0, (null))

Fontconfig warning: "/usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/05-reset-dirs-sample.conf", line 6: unknown element "reset-dirs"
WARNING | cannot add library /home/letorbi/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed
INFO    | added library /home/letorbi/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How can I get more information and **is there a workaround to prevent the segfault?**

For what it's worth, Wayland EGL is able to start the emulator somehow, but I see nothing but a black screen on the device. X11 is working, but I'd like to stay on Wayland if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work around the segmentation fault, by disabling the Vulkan support for AVDs. This can be easily achieved by adding the following line to the file ***~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini***:

```
Vulkan = off
```

I've got this hint from [an answer in a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63244455/398844). This answer also suggests to add `GLDirectMem = on`, but that line was not needed to solve my problem. However, some benchmarking revealed that it might improve the performance a little bit, so you might want to add that line as well.